# convert Messaging.messaging().fcmToken to string?

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken;
let fixedUrl : String = String("\(loadUrl)?os=I&fcm_token=\(token)&tval=tt\(appVer)")
let url : URL? = URL(string:fixedUrl)
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

this code produces crash if i dont allow push permission during app start.
How can I express

```
token = fcmToken? fcmToken : ""
```

in swift way?

Answer (score 0):

let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken ?? "";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).